# Find and move files to appropriate directories using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, mv

I have below setup and I want to find and move files.

I have files `/home/backup/abc/123.wav` and  `/home/backup/xyz/456.wav`.
Same directories exist at `/usr/src/abc`  and `/usr/src/xyz` which does not have any files.

I want to find .wav files from home_dir and move them to particular dest_dir.

So 123.wav should move to /usr/src/abc and 456.wav should move to /usr/src/xyz.
I am using below command for that.

```
home_dir=/home/backup/
dest_dir=/usr/src/
cd $home_dir && find . -iname "*.wav" -exec mv {} $dest_dir \;
```

But all the .wav files(123.wav and 456.wav) moved to /usr/src and not to its respective directories(/usr/src/abc  and /usr/src/xyz).

Is it possible to achieve what I want ?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cp --parents` option with `find` to create parent directories of each file being copied:

```
home_dir=/home/backup/
dest_dir=/usr/src/
cd "$home_dir"

find . -iname "*.wav" -exec cp --parents {} "$dest_dir" \; -delete
```

Comment: I want to move the files.When I use 
find . -iname "*.wav" -exec cp --parents {} "$dest_dir" \; 
.wav files copy as 123 and 456 not as 123.wav and 456.wav.

Comment: After my suggested `cp` command you can use `find . -iname "*.wav" -delete` to delete all files from source directory.

Comment: .wav files are generate randomly so if I use delete command after copy command, is there any chances to delete any file that will not be copied ?

Comment: You can do both in same `find` also: `find . -iname "*.wav" -exec cp --parents {} "$dest_dir" \; -delete`

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot easier if `mv` had a `--parents` option, but unfortunately it doesn't.  It's best to use `mv` instead of `cp` because `cp` will copy all the data unnecessarily if the source and destination directories are on the same filesystem.  if you've got Bash 4 (which supports `globstar`) you could do it like this:

```
home_dir=/home/backup/
dest_dir=/usr/src/

shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob

for src_wav in "$home_dir"/**/*.wav ; do
    rel_wav=${src_wav#$home_dir/}
    dst_wav=$dest_dir/$rel_wav
    dst_parent=${dst_wav%/*}
    [[ -d $dst_parent ]] || mkdir -p -- "$dst_parent"
    mv -- "$src_wav" "$dst_wav"
done
```

Comment: I will try this too.Thanks.